# Optimising a basic group_by aggregation

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pymongo

It's possible that I'm just wildly naive but I would have thought that this aggregation would be quicker considering it's somewhat simple - no complex joins of any kind and all the data is in a single simple table.

It's also likely that the answer to this question is one of data size and not one of an efficient query or database set up, but I'm looking for a fast aggregation and sum of the following table:

| id | time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 1 | 22 |
| 2 | 17 |

The idea is to group by id and sum the time column. There may be anywhere between 300 and 500 names, with an average of 3M rows. In both a mongo and sql the id column is indexed.

Using pymongo is giving my around 3 seconds to perform the query on a static database of 3M entries while SQLAlchemy is giving me around 2 seconds on the same data.

Can I safely assume that it *should* take that long for 3 million entries, or have I clearly missed something, like a direct SQL query (as opposed to doing a python based sqlalchemy query) might be faster?

Also, note that I would like the results in JSON, which I think is the slow part of sqlalchemy - creating the python object of the result to then send on.

I'm familiar and confident in using SQLAlchemy and pymongo, but not much else so if there's another database solution that's quicker i will definitely consider it because I would like to run this query frequently and a 2-4 second lag is a little unpleasant.

Comment: Would adding a method to the model for the table to returns the result in a list of objects format [{}, {}, ...] be more performant?

Comment: Using `pymongo`, I ran the `"$group"` pipeline and converted to a JSON string with `bson.json_util.dumps` on a MongoDB Atlas server and also on my laptop.  For 3M docs with 500 unique `"id"`s (inserted in the databases with [`mgodatagen`](https://github.com/feliixx/mgodatagen)), the Atlas server (v5.0.14) took about 4 secs and my local MongoDB server (v6.1.1) took about 2.6 secs.  Is your collection updated frequently?  Could a [On-Demand Materialized View](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#on-demand-materialized-view--initial-creation) be helpful here?

Comment: Thanks @rickhg12hs. I realised i made a small error in the question, although it doesn't appear to affect your performance much - there are between 3000 and 5000 unique IDs. It does get updated regularly (1-20/s), but is not requested frequently, so an on-demand materialized view might work. The only issue is that we're trying to allow on-demand filtering of the results too, say by excluding specific IDs or a few other fields not shown (like whether a mask is applied or not). I guess it might be possible to separate these into different collections and aggregate the materialized results?

Comment: Looks like you have a few possibilities to explore.  There's no "free lunch", but increasing storage to reduce time can be a valid approach.  Moving "filtering time" before the operational query could also work.  I don't know of a way to be sure other than benchmarking.

Comment: Agreed. Just need to generate a dummy dataset and play around with different options to find the best balance between performance and customisation. I guess the original question was just to get an answer to 'what is normal', and it seems what I'm getting is normal. I did have another method which was an on-the-fly once per second that only calculates based on new and expired data and wrote the result to another table, but that doesn't allow for bespoke querying. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though this processing time is normal and that the only way to speed things up is to use the [On-Demand Materialized View](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#on-demand-materialized-view--initial-creation) recommended by [@rickhg12hs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1409374/rickhg12hs) to generate some common pre-calculated datasets and if the query required is more complicated than these defaults, then just accept the 2-5 second processing time.